# how do you test that Rails mailer credentials are valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, actionmailer

I've got a mailer sending through a GMail account, and I want to test that ActionMailer can actually log in to GMail's SMTP server with the credentials I've given it. What's the best way to test this?

Comment: What are you trying to test? That your credentials are correct, or that ActionMailer actually works?

Comment: That the credentials are correct. I believe that ActionMailer works. Just want my tests to catch it if I manually change a password but forget to update my code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a full-stack solution, but you can check that the server authentication happens correctly by using Net::SMTP directly. The Mail gem that Rails 3 uses to send ActionMailer emails uses Mail like so (with your ActionMailer.smtp_settings):

```
  #line 96 of mail-2.2.7/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb
  smtp = Net::SMTP.new(settings[:address], settings[:port])
  if settings[:enable_starttls_auto]
    smtp.enable_starttls_auto if smtp.respond_to?(:enable_starttls_auto) 
  end

  smtp.start(settings[:domain], settings[:user_name], settings[:password],
   settings[:authentication]) do |smtp|
     smtp.sendmail(message, envelope_from, destinations)
     # @Mason: this line need not be included in your code. SMTP#start throws
     # a Net::SMTPAuthenticationError if the authentication was not successful.
     # So just putting this call to #start with an empty block in a method and
     # calling assert_no_raise Net::SMTPAuthenticationError should do the trick.
     # The empty block is necessary so that the connection gets closed.
     # Reference #{rubydir}/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb for more info.
  end
```

Looks like ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings is accessible too:

```
  settings = ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings
```

Putting that in your test and commenting out the line spoken of above should have a working example for you.

Comment: awesome. Thanks Tim, and sorry for taking so long to try it out and accept!

Answer (score 8):

```rb
smtp = Net::SMTP.new settings[:address], settings[:port]
smtp.enable_starttls_auto if settings[:enable_starttls_auto]
smtp.start(settings[:domain]) do
  expect {
    smtp.authenticate settings[:user_name], settings[:password], settings[:authentication]
  }.to_not raise_error
end
```

Calling `authenticate` will raise a `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` if the authentication fails.

Otherwise, it will return a `Net::SMTP::Response`, and calling `status` on the response will return `"235"`.

Comment: As far as I know in my own testing, `authenticate` does not raise an error when authentication fails. It returns the following message in `.string` if a wrong password is supplied, for example: `535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password`.